# JS library that "reloads" a page to mimic pre-load code injection?

Tags: javascript

Apologies if the title is vague, but it's not the easiest question to describe. Currently, if you want to wrap/overload a built-in function in the browser, such as `XmlHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(){return oldOpen(...)}`, and you want to do it before any scripts in the page execute, you'd need to use a browser extension/addon that executes before the document starts being parsed. The thing is, browser extensions often have a low conversion rate of users who agree to install them. I'd love to be able to use bookmarklets to do the same thing (and Pinterest has shown that bookmarklets aren't a barrier for them!). But alas, bookmarklets by definition run long after the document has loaded.

What I'd like to do, and what I think is theoretically possible, is to fake a page reload, but with a script inserted already. The process would look something like this:

1. Download, via XHR, the original document from `window.location`.
2. Remove all elements from the DOM, including all the script tags. Maybe throw up a nice splash screen for a good user experience.
3. Clear all timeouts and intervals (on FF and Chrome the IDs seem to count up from 1, so no a priori knowledge is needed AFAIK).
4. Delete/undefine all keys in `window` and `document` that aren't there in a blank document... which, given that there might be some extensions installed, might require some iframe trickery/messaging to actually get a reference blank document.
5. Inject your scripts into the now-blank document.
6. Re-insert all the tags from the XHR'd original document, including the scripts, which should then reload and re-execute in your new context.
7. Take down the splash screen, and you're good to go!

Now, I'd be perfectly willing to take a stab at this and open source it, but has anyone tried something like this before? It'll be a lot of work, and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel unless what we're using now is the equivalent of square boulders on sticks.

Comment: I get the feeling that you could implement this with an iframe.

Comment: For reference, this is the project: https://github.com/bpartridge/angryponies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or rewrite the current url into a new window with your appropriate js shim.

```
(function() {

var scriptSrc = 'http://example.com/shim.js';
var rq = new XMLHttpRequest; rq.open('get', '', false);
rq.send();
var text = rq.responseText.replace('<head', '<script src="' + scriptSrc + '"></script><head');
var win = window.open();
win.document.open();
win.document.write(text);
win.document.close();

})();
```

Comment: Wow, I never expected this to work! I would expect the origin of the new page to be "about:blank", meaning that cross-domain requests wouldn't work, but apparently Chrome (EDIT: and Firefox) set it to the origin of the original page and everything's great.

Comment: Also, this works with an iframe, in case anyone else finds this. If you size the iframe to fit the whole page, it looks like the page was just reloaded, but with your shim!